# AWS S3 Java file upload without access keys/credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS,
I used AWS CLI to locally configure my AWS credentials, as I can't have an IAM role attached to my laptop,
I can see my credentials properly configured though the Eclipse IDE's AWS Tool kit plugin.
I referred this answer - [AWS S3 upload without access and secret key in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062813/aws-s3-upload-without-access-and-secret-key-in-java),

Can someone help me understand how do I set in code, which region the S3 bucket lies in?
 
or does it fetch the region, from the one set during the aws configure command?
As I get an error when I try to use `s3client.setRegion` method.

I am not able to test this code locally, it's throwing me the following error -

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
```

**Following is my code to upload file to AWS S3** -

```
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                      .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false))
                      .build();
//s3client.setRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1));
PutObjectResult result = s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, BASE_PATH + localFile.getName(), localFile));
```

**Complete error log -**

```
The legacy profile format requires the 'profile ' prefix before the profile name. The latest code does not require such prefix, and will consider it as part of the profile name. Please remove the prefix if you are seeing this warning.
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.handleError(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:180)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:159)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.getCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:82)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:141)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1118)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:758)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:722)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:665)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:647)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:511)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4227)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4174)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1722)
    at com.atrium.crud.service.PedestrianServiceImpl.savePedestrianSurvey(PedestrianServiceImpl.java:73)
    at com.atrium.crud.controller.PedestrianController.savePedestrianSurvey(PedestrianController.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.ConnectionUtils.connectToEndpoint(ConnectionUtils.java:47)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:106)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:77)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider$InstanceMetadataCredentialsEndpointProvider.getCredentialsEndpoint(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:156)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:121)
    ... 69 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
AmazonS3Client amazons3 = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
```

`ProfileCredentialsProvider` will find hidden folder `.aws` & file credentials in your home directory.

Answer (score 3):

A better solution would be to use a credentials provider chain. That way your application can use instance profile credentials in production and fall back to profile credentials on your development machine.

For example:

```
AWSCredentialsProviderChain providerChain = new AWSCredentialsProviderChain(
            InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance(),
            new ProfileCredentialsProvider()
    );

AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                  .withCredentials(providerChain)
                  .build();
```

This will first try the instance profile to get access and fall back to profile credentials. You can add as many providers as you like as long as they implement [the AWSCredentialsProvider interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.html).

Alternatively, use the [default provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) which will try providers in this order:

- Environment Variables - `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` (RECOMMENDED since they are recognized by all the AWS SDKs and CLI except for .NET), or `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` (only recognized by Java SDK)
- Java System Properties - `aws.accessKeyId` and `aws.secretKey`
- Credential profiles file at the default location (`~/.aws/credentials`) shared by all AWS SDKs and the AWS CLI
- Credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 container service if `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` environment variable is set and security manager has permission to access the variable,
- Instance profile credentials delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service

[Source](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/secure-local-development-with-the-profilecredentialsprovider/)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());
```

make sure that your aws.properties (which has following keys) in classpath

```
accessKey=AKIAIB6FA52IMGLREIIB
secretKey=NQjJWKT+WZOUOrQ2Pr/WcRey3PnQFaGMJ8nRoaAA
```

Comment: When I did aws configure and set my creds, they got stored in ~/.aws/config location I think, Which I found when I fired the following command - aws configure list, Is that correct location?

Comment: This is correct.. And these credentials will be used while using AWS CLI.. If you want to access services from Java code; this way would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert the region in your builder statement e.g

```
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
         .withCredentials(newInstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false))
         .withRegion("eu_central_1")
         .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                   .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
                   .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue "Unable to load credentials from service endpoint"
I tried this and working fine, dont use InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance()

```
@Bean
public AmazonS3 getS3Client() {
  return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
      .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
      .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1).build();
}
```